# "Security was a privilege of expensive locks"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Can I say "security was a privilege of expensive locks"?

I am rechecking a translation, and the use of *privilege* in this context seems too weird to me. Isn't "privilege" used only with people?

Comment: It sounds weird to me. What point is it trying to make?

Comment: If you have to use *privilege*, consider- _"security was privileged by expensive locks"_.

Comment: Trying to say, that in the past, only the expensive locks were highly secure.

Comment: Not to change to original sentence too much, I would use: "security was a property of expensive locks"  What do you think?

Comment: It's an antropomorphism, yes. Which means it might work perfectly fine or be completely out of place, depending on the context. With locks, it's much more likely to be the latter, as you are probably not translating a sci-fi book about a lock people from planet Metalsmith. As an aside, `´` is the [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B4). It's something you put atop of letters. A letter part, not a punctuation mark. Do not misuse it as an apostrophe. That's like replacing a b with a d. They might look very similar, but they don't mean remotely the same thing.

Comment: A *function* or *product* of expensive locks ...?

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the word privilege of a lock. It is a privilege to possess an expensive lock and it is a privilege to have security.

> *Security was a privilege of those with expensive locks* `(Reg's favourite :) )`

Other versions

> *Higher security was enjoyed through the use of expensive locks*

or

> *Expensive locks gave the dwellers the privilege of heightened security*

Comment: Nice sentences, however, this is only technical translation, need something not complicated for non-native speakers. My question is if you think, this use of privilege might be correct or not.

Comment: +1 for the last suggestion in particular, an elegant fix indeed. And @Zdenka: if it's specifically for non-native speakers with insufficient command of the language, why are you even translating it? They could just use the original instead.

Comment: mplungjan, now you gave me arguments. It  is easy and explaining, thank you. @RegDwight - it is an official, company translation, they gave it to me to recheck if everything was fine. I am not a native speaker, less perfect in English, however, they are things I see strange, but cannot explain why.

Comment: Sorry Reg - I moved the last suggestion to the top

Answer (score 0):

No. (Although I like the idea!)

There is also the word **preserve**:

`The civil service became the preserve of the educated middle class.`

or

`This book shows that science writing is by no means the preserve of specialists.`

but again, it's normally applied to people, not locks.

Depending on the target audience for your translation, you should probably consider consider using a simpler phrase, to convey the required meaning in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the anthropomorphism identified by the other answers, I would suggest wording it like this:

> "only expensive locks provided any security"